# Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): Expected space separating root-level values at [Source: 2021-06-06T10:50:00Z; line: 1, column: 6]

Tags: java, swagger, vert.x, swagger-codegen

Using swagger vertx codegen, i have generated some verticle files. In one example, i try to allow the user to pass me a datetime string. My swagger-spec is as follows:

```
  /test/my/endpoint:
    post:
      tags:
        - endpoint
      summary: test
      description: test
      operationId: test
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: from_date
          in: query
          description: |
            The start date for the report. Must be used together with `to_date`.
          required: false
          type: string
          format: date-time
        - name: to_date
          in: query
          description: |
            The end date for the report. Must be used together with `from_date`.
          required: false
          type: string
          format: date-time
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/TestSchema'
        '500':
          description: internal server error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/TestSchema'
      x-contentType: application/json
      x-accepts: application/json
```

Vertx-Swagger Codgen then in the verticle generates something like this:

```
// in MyApiVerticle.java
final Handler<Message<JsonObject>> postMyHandler = message -> {
        try {
            OffsetDateTime fromDate = null;
            if(message.body().getString("from_date") != null) {
                fromDate = Json.mapper.readValue(message.body().getString("from_date"), OffsetDateTime.class);
            } catch (Exception e) { ... }
}
```

When i try this endpoint with a string like this:

```
2021-06-06T10:50:00Z
```

I get the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): Expected space separating root-level values  at [Source: 2021-06-06T10:50:00Z; line: 1, column: 6]
```

The request being sent looks like this:

```
http request:
http://localhost:8080/api/test/my/endpoint?from_date=2021-06-06T10%3A50%3A00Z&to_date=2021-06-06T11%3A50%3A00Z

curl:
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8080/api/test/my/endpoint?from_date=2021-06-06T10%3A50%3A00Z&to_date=2021-06-06T11%3A50%3A00Z' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -d ''
```

If i print out `message.body()` i see the following before the exception is thrown:

```
{"from_date":"2021-06-06T10:50:00Z","to_date":"2021-06-06T11:50:00Z"}
```

If i pass in `0` for both the `from_date` and `to_date` value, it appears to work and the date then becomes `1970-01-01T00:00Z' for both fields.

How do i fix this? Is the format of the string incorrect? After doing some digging around, it seems correct: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/

The detailed exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: 2021-06-06T10:50:00Z; line: 1, column: 6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1586)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:521)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:450)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportMissingRootWS(ParserMinimalBase.java:466)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._verifyRootSpace(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1598)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._parsePosNumber(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1248)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:705)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3847)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3792)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2797)
    at com.my.testƒƒ.api.MyApiVerticle.lambda$new$0(MyApiVerticle.java:31)
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.deliver(HandlerRegistration.java:223)
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.handle(HandlerRegistration.java:200)
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.EventBusImpl.lambda$deliverToHandler$3(EventBusImpl.java:533)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:339)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please could you show the complete JSON of the request you're sending?

Comment: @JonSkeet this POST request doesn't take a JSON body atm. So the request looks like this: http://localhost:8080/api/test/my/endpoint?from_date=2021-06-06T10%3A50%3A00Z&to_date=2021-06-06T11%3A50%3A00Z

Comment: I'm far from a Swagger expert, but the code `message.body().getString("from_date")` appears to be trying to get a `from_date` property from the *body* of a message. I'd expect JSON of `{ "from_date": "2021-06-06T10:50:00Z" }` for example. If you're not using a message body in the request, why does your code refer to a body? What is `message` in this case? The fact that it's a JsonParseException when you don't have any JSON is particularly suspicious. It's possible this is all an artifact of Swagger and Vertx, but from an outsider's perspective it looks very odd.

Comment: It's a POST, but there's no body--the params are in the URL.

Comment: @JonSkeet so the reason i don't think that it has to do with the body is because if i make the request like this: http://localhost:8080/api/test/my/endpoint?from_date=0&to_date=0 then in the backend i get a print statement that shows me the date was received as "1970-01-01T00:00Z" for both the from_date and to_date fields. I'm assuming it has something to do with the format of the date i'm passing in

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like it may well be vert.x-specific though. It would still help if you'd show the type of `message` to make it easier to investigate - that generated code really is *very* confusing if there's no body...

Comment: @JonSkeet the message variable comes from here: `final Handler<Message<JsonObject>> postMyHandler = message -> { ... }` if i print message.body() i see this: `{"from_date":"2021-06-06T10:50:00Z","to_date":"2021-06-06T11:50:00Z"}` before the exception is thrown

Comment: Please put all of that in the question - that's valuable information.

Comment: It would also be really helpful if you'd put a more complex stack trace in the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Okay, added above in the question

Comment: fromDate = OffsetDateTime.parse(message.body().getString("from_date"), java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);

Comment: @Govind that code is generated and hence not something i want to touch/change

Comment: I saw a very similar error when my program parsed a date in a JSON String format without double quotes.